# With one XML file, how do I populate different pages with individual XML elements?

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0

Hi was just wondering how I could use one XML file to populate to different files.  For example, in the XML below how would I get the first XML block "cooking" to show up on cooking.html and the second XML block "children" to show up on children.html?  I know how to make them all display on one page but not on individual pages.

```
<book category="COOKING">
  <title lang="en">Everyday Italian</title>
  <author>Giada De Laurentiis</author>
  <year>2005</year>
  <price>30.00</price>
</book>

<book category="CHILDREN">
 <title lang="en">Harry Potter</title>
 <author>J K. Rowling</author>
 <year>2005</year>
 <price>29.99</price>
</book>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using some server-side scripting, you could parse only the COOKING-category when requesting cooking.html etc.

Though, if you are getting the XML-data directly from the HTML-code, then I would recommend splitting the XML-file by category. Alternately you could have a XML-file which includes separate XML-files sorted by category. [Described here.](http://xml.silmaril.ie/includes.html)

Sorry I couldn't give you a better solution.

Comment: Thanks for your help!  I will look into having mutltiple XML files inside of one parent XML file.  Ideally it would be nice though to only have one XML file for the whole project.

Comment: Agreed! I'll be watching to if anybody knows how to achieve this with HTML.